# How can I convert coordinates on a square to coordinates on a circle?

Tags: math, coordinate-systems

I'm developing an indie video game, and have been operating under the assumption that because the thumbstick on my controller has a circular range of motion, it returns "circular" coordinates; that is, Cartesian coordinates constrained to a circular area (of radius 1). In fact, the coordinates are "square"; e.g., the top-right thumbstick position registers as x=1,y=1. When I convert the coordinates from Cartesian to polar, the magnitude can exceed 1 - which has the effect that the player can move faster diagonally than they can vertically or horizontally.

So, to clarify, I want to record the position of an analog thumbstick in terms of a direction and magnitude, where the magnitude is between 0 and 1. The thumbstick returns coordinates on a square plane, so simply converting the coordinates from Cartesian to polar is not sufficient. I think I need to convert the coordinate *space*, but that is pressing the limits of my monkey brain.

Comment: Does is take up the "entire" square or does it return coordinates that lie within something that already looks like a circle? E.g. make sure that you can (or can't) take the sqrt-magnitude.

Comment: What (x,y) do you get with the stick straight up? Also, is your stick analog or switches? Can you get values like (0.5,0.5)?

Comment: Yes, coordinates are distributed all over a square, including the corners.

Comment: Then I might delete my answer. :-) It sounds like the driver software is pre-warping the values.

Comment: Nosredna: I think you're right. Something (driver? DirectInput?) is mapping the coordinates to a square. I wonder why. I would almost always prefer a circle.

Comment: @Metaphile don't be such a circle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [Mapping a Square to a Circle](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html). There's also a nice visualization for the mapping. You get:

```
xCircle = xSquare * sqrt(1 - 0.5*ySquare^2)
yCircle = ySquare * sqrt(1 - 0.5*xSquare^2)
```

Comment: Based on the visualization, I think this is _exactly_ what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

The mapping is not unique.  There are many other solutions to this question.

For example, this mapping will also work

> u = x √(x² + y² - x²y²) / √(x² + y²)
>
> v = y √(x² + y² - x²y²) / √(x² + y²)

where **(u,v)** are circular disc coordinates and **(x,y)** are square coordinates.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here are some images to illustrate the non-uniqueness of the mapping and its inverse.

[image: circular Brady bunch]

---

[image: squared Boston Celtics]

`For a C++ implementation` of this other mapping, go to
http://squircular.blogspot.com/2015/09/fg-squircle-mapping.html
See http://squircular.blogspot.com for more images of mapping results.

See also ["Analytical Methods for Squaring the Disc"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344) for a paper discussing different mapping equations with proofs and derivations.

Comment: Nice. How did you generate the figures (language/library)?

Comment: I wrote a simple image processing program in C++ that uses different mapping equations per pixel. See the link to sample code link.  Libpng is useful reading and writing out PNG files

Answer (score 0):

Divide each value by the magnitude to normalize all values to a unit vector, e.g.

```
magn = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
newx = magn > 1.0 ? x / magn : x;
newy = magn > 1.0 ? y / magn : y;
```

However, this may have the effect of clipping the magnitude instead of normalizing for the interior values.. That is, you'll get the same value for a controller pushed "fully" into the upper-left and a controller *almost* pushed fully into the same direction.

Comment: I definitely don't want to clip the magnitude. I already have a deadzone. The two together would significantly reduce the stick's effective range of motion. I think Eemeli has the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm many years late but I thought I'd share what I was able to figure out for this problem after going back and looking into it deeper. Thought there was a better solution but couldn't find one.

I recently had to do something similar in JavaScript and created a way to normalize(or map?) the `X` and `Y` of a unit square to a quarter unit circle, deriving the velocity as `V`, and Direction as `d`. This was used to generate flow field grid points with random values.

I used `(n * 2) - 1` to get the `X` and `Y` values, where `n` is a random number between `0` and `1`. The values of X and Y are between `-1` and `1`.

First, we get the hypotenuse, or `h`, of `X,Y`.

> `h = √(X² + Y²)`

Then we get the angle, as `∆`, between `X` and `h` as an absolute value `|•|`. We get the absolute value so we don't get a negative `V`

> `∆ = |arcsin(X/h)|`

Now that we have angle, we can extend the hypotenuse along that angle. We do so by maxing out `X` to 1. Well call this `h'`

> `h' = 1/cos(∆)`

Because we used the absolute value, this changes the orientation along the origin point. We account for that like so.

> `q = 45(π/180)`
>
> `if (∆ ≥ q) h' = 1/cos(q - (∆ mod q))`

With that, now we can normalize `h` with `h'`.

> `V = h/h'`

To get the true `∆`, or `d`, we're going to have to correct for it's orientation with some case logic.

We'll be using degrees converted to radians, then using the `∆` calculated before.

The logic is as follows:

```
 (X ≥ 0)?(Y ≥ 0)?toRad(90) mod ∆: ∆ + toRad(270):(Y ≤ 0)? ∆ + toRad(180): ∆ + toRad(90)
```

To clarify, each case coresponds to a quadrant of the grid/circle.

- If `X ≥ 0` and `Y ≥ 0`, then `toRad(90) mod ∆`
- If `X ≥ 0` and `Y < 0`, then `∆ + toRad(270)`
- If `X < 0` and `Y ≤ 0`, then `∆ + toRad(180)`
- If `X < 0` and `Y > 0`, then `∆ + toRad(90)`

This will give you the rotation of direction in radians. Note that it may be useful to reset 360° back to 0.

That's basically what I came up with. In a way it interpolates the values so that it stays between 0 and 1, so values like `1,0` and `1,1` both equal to 1. Where `1,0` is 100% to right and `1,1` is 100% to the top/forward right. Negative values for `X` and `Y` just flip orientation along there respective axis. If `X,Y` are equal to 0, then `V` and `d` are also 0.

I hope this helps someone avoid a headache in the future.