# How can I convert coordinates on a circle to coordinates on a square?

Tags: math, coordinate-systems

I'm currently working on a game in LBP2 that has modify the way a controller gives input.  This question:
[How can I convert coordinates on a square to coordinates on a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621831/how-can-i-convert-coordinates-on-a-square-to-coordinates-on-a-circle)
Has helped me quite a lot with what I am doing, but I do have one problem.  I need the inverse function of the one they give.  They go from square -> circle, and I've tried searching all over for how to map a circle to a square.

The function given in the previous question is:

> xCircle = xSquare * sqrt(1 - 0.5*ySquare^2)
>
> yCircle = ySquare * sqrt(1 - 0.5*xSquare^2)
>
> From [Mapping a Square to a Circle](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html)

My question is given xCircle and yCircle... how do I find xSquare and ySquare?

I've tried all of the algebra I know, filled up two pages of notes, tried to get wolfram alpha to get the inverse functions, but this problem is beyond my abilities.

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a%20%3D%20x%20*%20sqrt(1-y%5E2%2F2)%3B%20b%20%3D%20y%20*%20sqrt(1-x%5E2%2F2))

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103660/homeomorphism-from-square-to-unit-circle, http://www.flickr.com/photos/sbprzd/362529354/, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/144703

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> x = ½ √( 2 + u² - v² + 2u√2 ) - ½ √( 2 + u² - v² - 2u√2 )
>   y = ½ √( 2 - u² + v² + 2v√2 ) - ½ √( 2 - u² + v² - 2v√2 )

Note on notation: I'm using x = xSquare , y = ySquare, u = xCircle and v = yCircle;

i.e. **(u,v)** are circular disc coordinates and **(x,y)** are square coordinates.

[image: grid mapping]

For a C++ implementation of the equations, go to
http://squircular.blogspot.com/2015/09/mapping-circle-to-square.html

See http://squircular.blogspot.com
for more example images.
Also, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06344 for the proof/derivation

This mapping is the inverse of

> u = x √( 1 - ½ y² )
>   v = y √( 1 - ½ x² )

---

P.S. The mapping is not unique.  There are other mappings out there. The picture below illustrates the non-uniqueness of the mapping.

[image: Boston Celtics squared]

Answer (score 1):

if you have xCircle and yCircle that means that you're on a circle with radius `R = sqrt(xCircle^2 + yCircle^2)`. Now you need to extend that circle to a square with half-side = R,

```
if (xCircle < yCircle)
     ySquare = R, xSquare = xCircle * R/yCircle
else
     xSquare = R, ySquare = yCircle * R/xCircle
```

this is for the first quadrant, for others you need some trivial tweaking with the signs

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing the solution above but the results are not satisfiying.
The square coordinates are not exact.

Here is a simple counter-example:

- Consider the point (x,y)=(0.75, 1) on the square.
- We map it to the circle with (u,v)=(0.53, 0.85) on the circle.
- Applying the expression above we get the new square coordinates

  (x',y')=(u/v,r)=(0.625543242, 1) with r=(u^2+v^2)^(1/2).

This point is close but not the expected precise solution.

I solved a root finding problem in order to get the inverse expression of the mapping from square to circle like above.
you need to solve the system equations like above:

```
I) u = x*(1-y^2/2)^(1/2)
II) v = y*(1-x^2/2)^(1/2)
```

One ends up with 8 root points as solution. One of the roots I implemented into Excel-VBA which I present here below and it works very fine.

```
' given the circle coordinates (u,v) caluclates the x coordinate on the square
Function circ2sqrX(u As Double, v As Double) As Double
    Dim r As Double, signX As Double, u2 As Double, v2 As Double, uuvv As Double, temp1 As Double
    u2 = u * u
    v2 = v * v
    r = Sqr(u2 + v2)
    signX = 1
    If v = 0 Or u = 0 Then
       circ2sqrX = u
       Exit Function
    End If
    If u < 0 Then
    signX = -1
    End If
    If Abs(u) = Abs(v) And r = 1 Then
       circ2sqrX = signX
       Exit Function
    End If
    uuvv = (u2 - v2) * (u2 - v2) / 4
    temp1 = 2 * Sqr(uuvv - u2 - v2 + 1)
    circ2sqrX = -((temp1 - u2 + v2 - 2) * Sqr(temp1 + u2 - v2 + 2)) / (4 * u)
End Function

' given the circle coordinates (u,v) caluclates the y coordinate on the square
' make use of symetrie property
Function circ2sqrY(u As Double, v As Double) As Double
    circ2sqrY=circ2sqrX(v,u)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this; here's one simple way.

Imagine a circle of radius *R* centred on the origin, and a square of side *2R* centred on the origin, we want to map all of the points within and on the boundary of the circle (with coordinates *(x,y)*) to points within and on the boundary of the square.  Note that we can also describe points within the circle using [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) *(r, ø)* (that's supposed to be a phi), where

> x = r cos ø,
>   y = r sin ø

(ie *r^2 = x^2 + y^2* and *r <= 1*).  Then imagine other coordinates *x' = a(ø) x = a(ø) r cos ø*, and *y' = a(ø) y* (ie, we decide that *a* won't depend on *r*).

In order to map the boundary of the circle (*r = 1*) to the boundary of the square (*x' = R*), we must have, for *ø < 45deg*, *x' = a(ø) R cos ø = R*, so we must have *a(ø) = 1/cos ø*.  Similarly, for *45 < ø < 90* we must have the boundary of the circle map to *y' = R*, giving *a(ø) = 1/sin ø* in that region.  Continuing round the circle, we see that *a(ø)* must always be positive, so the final mapping from the circle to the square is

> x' = a(ø) x,
>   y' = a(ø) y

where

> *ø* = |arctan *y/x*| = arctan |*y/x*|

and

> *a(ø) = 1/cos ø*, when *ø* <= 45 deg (ie, when *x < y*), and
>   *a(ø) = 1/sin ø*, when *ø* > 45 deg.

That immediately gives you the mapping in the other direction.  If you have coordinates *(x', y')* on the square (where *x' <= R* and *y' <= R*), then

> *x = x'/a(ø)*
>   *y = y'/a(ø)*

with *a(ø)* as above.

---

A much simpler mapping, though, is to calculate the *(r, ø)* for the desired position on the circle, and map that to *x' = r* and *y' = ø*.  That also maps every point in the circle into a rectangle, and vice versa, and might have better properties, *depending on what you want to do*.

So that's the real question: what is it you're actually aiming to do here?