# How to find point cordinates in a circle using radius and center cordinate

Tags: java, math, geometry, shapes

I am trying to map all circle cordinates to a flat surface using OpenGL fragment shader as shown in the picture. I know the radius and center point of the circle. So I am trying to use the below equation:

For a circle with origin (j, k) and radius r:

```
x(t) = r cos(t) + j
y(t) = r sin(t) + k
```

where you need to run this equation for t taking values within the range from 0 to 360, then you will get your x and y each on the boundary of the circle.

But I am facing below problem:

1. **Angle values are in degrees. Can I use that directly in the fragment shader code as the OpenGL cordinates are from 0.0 to 1.0?**

[image]

Comment: It is not clear - let you have radius 0.5 and want to map point 0.75, 0.75 from circle... To what?

Comment: @MBo I am mapping a circle to a rectangle

Comment: To rectangle perimeter or to inner point? Do you have discrete float coordinates inside the circle?

Comment: @MBo I want to map entire circle to a rectangle. I only have radius and angle with me. I want to know a way to use the angle in degrees with respect to OpenGL cordinates in the range of [0.0,1.0]

Comment: Also if there is any equation for finding out x,y position for all points in the circle without using angle values?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to map circle points to square and vice versa. For simplicity circle center is (0,0) and radius is 1.

Let coordinate in square are (x,y) and corresponding coordinate in circle is (u, v).

So to get circle point:

```
u = x * sqrt(1 - y^2/2)
v = y * sqrt(1 - x^2/2)
```

Inverse formula is more complex:

```
x = (sqrt(2 + u*u-v*v+2*u*sqrt(2)) - sqrt(2 + u*u-v*v - 2*u*sqrt(2))) / 2
y = (sqrt(2 - u*u+v*v+2*v*sqrt(2)) - sqrt(2 - u*u+v*v - 2*v*sqrt(2))) / 2
```

Note that you perhaps want to get point at the circle corresponding to needed square point, so need only the first formula pair

P.S. Perhaps [I took formulas there years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211595/how-can-i-convert-coordinates-on-a-circle-to-coordinates-on-a-square)

---

If you need to walk through circle points with some step (while I doubt you really need this), you can scan Y-coordinates and get scanlines for X coordinates. Pseudocode:

```
for y = - R to R step d:
   L = sqrt(R*R-y*y)
   for x = -L to L step d:
      getPoint(cx + x, cy + y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the equations. I will try those as well