# Writing text in a circular path

Tags: python, go, gtk, cairo

I am trying to write a string of text in a circular path using **GTK/Cairo**, something like in this image (https://logosbynick.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/step8.png) :

[image]

Preferably I would like to do this in **Go**, but if I have a **C** or **Python** or whatever-example, I am confident that I can convert that to **Go** and **GoTK3** by myself.

So I found a **Python** example, https://eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Warped%20Text.html, that outputs the following image:

[image]

I figured I could easily simplify the code to write the text in a circle, after all, I have 30 years of programming experience in 15+ different languages. Unfortunately I have spent hours now trying, and I cannot make it work. Maybe I don't know enough **Python**, of maybe I don't know enough **GTK/Cairo** and text paths, or maybe my 30 years of programming experience is not enough.

So, this is a little bit embarrassing, but can someone help me out here?

[Edit]
Here is my closest attempt in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# [SNIPPET_NAME: Warped Text]
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: Cairo]
# [SNIPPET_DESCRIPTION: Generate some warped text]
# [SNIPPET_DOCS: http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/CairoTutorial]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: MPL]

import cairo
import math
import os


def warp_path(ctx, function):
    first = True

    for pathType, points in ctx.copy_path():
        if pathType == cairo.PATH_MOVE_TO:
            if first:
                ctx.new_path()
                first = False
            x, y = function(*points)
            ctx.move_to(x, y)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_LINE_TO:
            x, y = function(*points)
            ctx.line_to(x, y)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_CURVE_TO:
            x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = points
            x1, y1 = function(x1, y1)
            x2, y2 = function(x2, y2)
            x3, y3 = function(x3, y3)
            ctx.curve_to(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_CLOSE_PATH:
            ctx.close_path()


def circle(x, y):
    radius = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    theta = math.sinh(y/radius)
    x_new = radius*math.sin(theta)
    y_new = radius*math.cos(theta)
    return x_new, y_new


Width, Height = 512, 512
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, Width, Height)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
solid_pattern = context.get_source()

# background
context.rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)
context.fill()

# foreground
context.set_source(solid_pattern)
context.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
context.select_font_face("Sans")
context.set_font_size(10)

# circle text
context.new_path()
context.move_to(20, 150)
# context.arc(256, 256, 200, 0, 2*math.pi)
context.text_path("circle test circle test circle test circle test circle test circle test")
warp_path(context, circle)
context.fill()

surface.write_to_png(os.path.expanduser("~") + "/temp/warpedtext.png")
```

which generates this image:
[image]

[Edit 2] I think I need a function that transforms the rectangle to the circle like this (if it is possible to understand). Then I should be able to write the text to (0,0) and see it transform to a circle, I believe. I will work on that tomorrow. :

[image]

Comment: Did you followed any [Cairo Tutorial](https://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/) ? Or their [Documentation](https://www.cairographics.org/tutorial/)?

Comment: I have read the documentation you linked to, but that didn't help me. So I started to work on the example above, and I failed at that too. The tutorial you linked to I have also checked out, but all the text examples were different versions of writing text in a normal straight line. So no help there either...

Comment: After I read this answer, I think I need a completely new transformation function:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621831/how-can-i-convert-coordinates-on-a-square-to-coordinates-on-a-circle
I will work on that, now that I pretty much understand what kind of function I need.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is as far as I have come:

[image: Closest so far]

using the Python code below, and the result is ugly and not at all what I wanted. The beginning and end are warped and not positioned where I expected them to be. Anyway, I am giving up on this little project for now, I might take it up again if someone comes up with a perfect transformation equation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# [SNIPPET_NAME: Warped Text]
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: Cairo]
# [SNIPPET_DESCRIPTION: Generate some warped text]
# [SNIPPET_DOCS: http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/CairoTutorial]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: MPL]

import cairo
import math
import os


def warp_path(ctx, function):
    first = True

    for pathType, points in ctx.copy_path():
        if pathType == cairo.PATH_MOVE_TO:
            if first:
                ctx.new_path()
                first = False
            x, y = function(*points)
            ctx.move_to(x, y)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_LINE_TO:
            x, y = function(*points)
            ctx.line_to(x, y)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_CURVE_TO:
            x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = points
            x1, y1 = function(x1, y1)
            x2, y2 = function(x2, y2)
            x3, y3 = function(x3, y3)
            ctx.curve_to(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

        elif pathType == cairo.PATH_CLOSE_PATH:
            ctx.close_path()


def circle(x, y):
    radius = -y
    theta = -math.sin(x * math.pi/2) + math.pi
    x_new = radius * math.sin(theta)
    y_new = radius * math.cos(theta)

    return x_new, y_new


Width, Height = 512, 512
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, Width, Height)
context = cairo.Context(surface)
solid_pattern = context.get_source()

# background
context.rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)
context.fill()

# foreground
context.set_source(solid_pattern)
context.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
context.select_font_face("Sans")
context.set_font_size(0.05)

SCALE = 256
CENTER = 1

# circle text
context.new_path()
context.scale(SCALE, SCALE)
context.translate(CENTER, CENTER)
context.move_to(-0.98, -0.95)
context.text_path("Administration Settings Sound & Video Programming Office Games Silicon")
warp_path(context, circle)
context.fill()

surface.write_to_png(os.path.expanduser("~") + "/temp/warpedtext.png")
```